# Event not working

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am new to Tridion Event System. I have written a small code.

```
[TcmExtension("MyEventHandlerExtension")]
public class EH : TcmExtension
{
    public EH()
    {
        Subscribe();
    }
    public void Subscribe()
    {
        //EventSystem.Subscribe<Component, DeleteEventArgs>(HandlerForInitiated, EventPhases.Initiated);
        EventSystem.Subscribe<Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Page, Tridion.ContentManager.Extensibility.Events.PublishOrUnPublishEventArgs>(HandlerForCommitted, EventPhases.All);
    }

    private void HandlerForCommitted(IdentifiableObject subject, PublishOrUnPublishEventArgs args, EventPhases phase)
    {

        TDSE obj = new TDSE();
        Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.TDS.Publication pub = obj.GetPublication("tcm:0-150-1");
        Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.TDS.Page pubPage = obj.GetPage("tcm:150-12374-64", pub);
        pubPage.Publish("tcm:0-1-65538", false, true, false, default(DateTime), default(DateTime), default(DateTime));

    }
}
```

using this code i wanted to publish a page everytime when a publish and unpublish event occur.
I build this code and register its path in tridion config file . 
But its not working.Please Help

Comment: Please mark one of the solutions below if they solved your problem

Comment: FYI, it probably failed because you didn't call Initialize and Impersonate on the TDSE. But as the others have stated, you shouldn't be using the old TOM anyway -- use TOM.NET.

Answer (score 8):

Ok, first of all remove all your TDSE code, you should use TOM.NET. You can get session as `subject.Session`

Then make sure you have registered this extension in `Tridion.ContentManager.config` and restarted your system

And finally - if something doesn't work, just add simple code that will create a file in your `HandlerForCommitted` whenever event occurs, this way you will be able to see if your extension get executed.

Answer (score 6):

The 2011 Event System uses the TOM.NET API and not the TOM API.  Please do not create new TDSE objects in the 2011 Event System.  Even though you can reference the old Interop libraries, there is no reason to do so with 2011.  Using the TOM.NET libraries you should see better performance and also the code is future-proof.

Mihai Cadariu has a [nice example](http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/05/publishing-from-template-code-using.html) where he uses TOM.NET to Publish a page from a Tridion Template.  Adjusting the code to check for previewmode or publish mode and setting your own user and priority (instead of reading it from the current transaction) should work well.

Below code from http://yatb.mitza.net/2012/05/publishing-from-template-code-using.html

```
public void Publish(Engine engine, String tcmUri, User user, PublishPriority priority)
{
    Session session = new Session(user.Title);

    PublishInstruction publishInstruction = new PublishInstruction(session);
    RenderInstruction renderInstruction = new RenderInstruction(session);
    renderInstruction.RenderMode = RenderMode.Publish; // work around. needs to be specified for binaries.
    publishInstruction.RenderInstruction = renderInstruction;

    List<IdentifiableObject> items = new List<IdentifiableObject>() { session.GetObject(tcmUri) };
    List<PublicationTarget> targets = new List<PublicationTarget>() { engine.PublishingContext.PublicationTarget };
    PublishEngine.Publish(items, publishInstruction, targets, priority);

    session.Dispose();
}

// called with
 PublishTransaction currentTransaction = TemplateUtils.GetPublishTransaction(engine);
    TemplateUtils.Publish(engine, itemUri, currentTransaction.Creator, currentTransaction.Priority);
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code seems to have the three things I "normally" forget:

1. the class is `public`
2. it extends `TcmExtension`
3. it has a `TcmExtension` attribute

If you've registered the class correctly in the configuration file, it should just be a matter of restarting the relevant module(s). In this case I'd expect those to be the Publisher and TcmServiceHost services.

After restarting those modules and triggering a publish action, you should see an event being logged (in the Windows event viewer) that your extension is being loaded.

If that even shows, it means your assembly is being loaded into the relevant Tridion process and the class is being recognized and instantiated.

If at this stage your handler doesn't fire you may have to consider listening to a different event. Whenever I want to interact with the publishing, I end up listening for the `SaveEventArgs` of a `PublishTransaction`, instead of the `PublishOrUnPublishEventArgs` on the `Page`.